# Pretty enumerate: fontawesome

Tags: symbols, packages, lists, enumitem, fontawesome

I am trying to realize for my book a nice enumeration with the arabic enumerate  up a specific symbol with fontawesome. In this package I have not finded a tennis ball, which was more suited to my taste.

Here there is my MWE and the screenshot of my code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{\tiny\arabic*}\,\textcolor{green}{\faBatteryFull}]
\item text text
\item second
\item third
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{\tiny\arabic*}\,\textcolor{orange}{\faBatteryThreeQuarters}]
\item  text text
\item another
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{\tiny\arabic*}\,\textcolor{yellow}{\faBatteryHalf}]
\item  text text
\item different
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{\tiny\arabic*}\,\textcolor{red}{\faBatteryQuarter}]
\item  text text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not able to create only one automatic block for enumeration as shown in the following image (it is adapted with paint):

[image]

Comment: What should happen if the counter grows larger than 4?

Comment: @siracusa I expected this question :-). The list stops at 4, since there are only 4 batteries with the font fontawesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that the updated version fits better.

## Upadated version

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\battery
\setbox\battery=\hbox{\faBatteryFull}

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\tiny\sffamily\the\cnt}%
  \fi
}

\def\Item{%
  \item[%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\battery{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
              \else{\sffamily\color{lightgray}XXX}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\Item text text
\Item TEXT
\Item another text
\Item some text
\Item some text
\end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\Item abc
\Item defg
\Item hijk
\Item lmno
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Original version

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\def\numberlabel{%
    {\tiny\sffamily\the\cnt\hskip.3em}}

\def\Item{%
    \item[%
    \numberlabel
    \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
    \else
        \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
        \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
                \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
                \else{\sffamily\color{lightgray}XXX}
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    ]\advance\cnt by 1}



\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\Item text text
\Item TEXT
\Item another text
\Item some text
\Item some text
\end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\Item abc
\Item defg
\Item hijk
\Item lmno
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't worry, absolutely, and remember that my principle is always to thank people who are polite, respectful and fair to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for the feedback. I moved the numbers above battery symbols.

Comment: I appreciate very much the correct people as you.

Comment: Your suggestions for lowering the level between the number on my last answer are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ti*K*z without using enumerate.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myenum}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\node at (0,0) (bat1) {\textcolor{green}{\faBatteryFull}}node[right=5mm]{#1};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
\node at (0,0) (bat2) {\textcolor{orange}{\faBatteryThreeQuarters}}node[right=5mm]{#2};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2)}]
\node at (0,0) (bat3) {\textcolor{yellow}{\faBatteryHalf}}node[right=5mm]{#3};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-3)}]
\node at (0,0) (bat4) {\textcolor{red}{\faBatteryQuarter}}node[right=5mm]{#4};
\end{scope}
\node at ([yshift=1mm] bat1.north){1};
\node at ([yshift=1mm] bat2.north){2};
\node at ([yshift=1mm] bat3.north){3};
\node at ([yshift=1mm] bat4.north){4};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\myenum{First text}
{$a+b$}
{Third text}
{$a=\frac{b^2}{c}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]