# Decrease the height of the enumerate aligned with the text

Tags: lists, enumerate, inline

Starting from MWE of very good user @Marian G. [Pretty enumerate: fontawesome](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499962/pretty-enumerate-fontawesome)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\battery
\setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\tiny\sffamily\the\cnt}%
  \fi
}

\def\Item{%
  \item[%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\battery{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
              \else{\sffamily\color{lightgray}XXX}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\Item text text
\Item TEXT
\Item another text
\Item some text
\Item some text
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\Item abc
\Item defg
\Item hijk
\Item lmno
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can the height between the number of the enumeration and the symbol be decreased?

I'd like something like this,

[image]

if it is possible. Thank you.

### ADDENDUM

With the code of the user @sive (that I have bit modificated) I have a problem of a little space between the first and the second row of the text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\battery
\setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\bfseries\tiny\sffamily[\the\cnt]}%
  \fi
}

\def\Item{%
  \item[%
    \raisebox{-0.85em}{%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\battery{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
              \else{\sffamily\color{lightgray}XXX}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }}%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\Item \lipsum[1]
\Item \lipsum[2]
\Item another text
\Item some text
\Item some text
\end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\Item abc
\Item defg
\Item hijk
\Item lmno
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\battery
\setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\bfseries\tiny\sffamily[\the\cnt]}%
  \fi
}

\def\Item{%
  \item[%
    \smash{\raisebox{-0.85em}{%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\battery{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
              \else{\sffamily\color{lightgray}XXX}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }}}%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\Item \lipsum[2]
\Item \lipsum[1]
\Item another text
\Item some text
\Item some text
\end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\Item abc
\Item defg
\Item hijk
\Item lmno
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]