# Error fontawesome5 on a specific preamble

Tags: enumitem, fontawesome, compilation-error

Referring to my recent question, to which I would like to express my thanks, [Symbol of the tennis ball](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501338/symbol-of-the-tennis-ball), I'm having a difficult to compilate it. In my book, as in this MWE, I have an error.

How can I eliminate it?

Related questions:

1. [Decrease the height of the enumerate aligned with the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500784/decrease-the-height-of-the-enumerate-aligned-with-the-text);
2. [Pretty enumerate: fontawesome](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499962/pretty-enumerate-fontawesome)

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 
\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\battery
\setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\bfseries\small\sffamily[\the\cnt]}%
  \fi
}

\def\Item{%
  \item[%
    \smash{\raisebox{-0.85em}{%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\battery{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
              \else{\sffamily\color{magenta}{\faBatteryEmpty}}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }}}%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\Item \lipsum[1]
\Item \lipsum[2]
\Item \lipsum[3]
\Item \lipsum[4]
\Item \lipsum[5]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### ERROR:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050)
>   entering extended mode
>   ("C:/Users/utente/Desktop/errore fonta5.tex"
>   LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
>   Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty"
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex")
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"))
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty")
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.ltd.tex"))
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"))
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontawesome5\fontawesome5.sty"
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty")
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontawesome5\fontawesome5-generic-helpe
>   r.sty"
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontawesome5\fontawesome5-mapping.def")
>   )) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty")

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_let:D 
l.10 \setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull                                        
?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\hbox` is a TeX primitive and it requires braces, even if the argument is a single token.

The line:

```
\setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull
```

should be:

```
\setbox\battery=\hbox{\faBatteryFull}
```

That's why TeX reports a missing `{` on that line:

```latex
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \tex_let:D
l.10 \setbox\battery=\hbox\faBatteryFull

?
```

The error message accuses `\tex_let:D` of causing the error because `\hbox` expands tokens (`\faBatteryFull`) looking for `to <dimen>` or `spread <dimen>` or `{`, and `\tex_let:D` is the first non-expandable token which doesn't match any of the above options.

The version with `fontawesome` (not 5) works because `\faBatteryFull` expands to `\faicon {battery-full}` which, in turn, expands to `{\csname faicon@battery-full\endcsname }`. The `{` is then seen by `\hbox` which then will contain exactly `\csname faicon@battery-full\endcsname`. It [works](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=46713663#46713663) by chance, but it is wrong code nevertheless.

---

Fixed code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 
\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\battery
\setbox\battery=\hbox{\faBatteryFull}

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\bfseries\small\sffamily[\the\cnt]}%
  \fi
}

\def\Item{%
  \item[%
    \smash{\raisebox{-0.85em}{%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\battery{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}\faBatteryFull}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBatteryHalf}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBatteryQuarter}
              \else{\sffamily\color{magenta}{\faBatteryEmpty}}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }}}%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\Item \lipsum[1]
\Item \lipsum[2]
\Item \lipsum[3]
\Item \lipsum[4]
\Item \lipsum[5]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works correctly, but when I use it into my preamble of my book I have this error: `("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/newtx\t1ntxtlf.fd")
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.138 \alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt\pointcount@
                                                  
? `

Comment: Wait. I try your 2nd edit. I see if this works. Thank you.

Comment: Your code (recently edited) is copied identically on my long preamble: but it gives the same error as before. `! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.138 \alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt\pointcount@
                                                  
?` Why doesn't it work if it's correct?

Comment: @Sebastiano The only change I made was adding `{` and `}` around   `\faBatteryFull`: the rest is the same code from your question. Strange, though... That error means you used too many `\newcount`s. But in modern systems that shouldn't happen. What TeX distribution (TeXLive, MiKTeX...) do you have, and what engine are you using (pdfTeX, XeTeX...)? Could you post the code somewhere (https://pastebin.com, for example) so I can check?

Comment: I have not twitter account, facebook etc...:-( to have a login. I have MikTeX (last version) W7 OS 32-bit.

Comment: @Sebastiano You don't need to login at Pastebin. But any other site you prefer is fine, I just need the code.

Comment: the fragment `\alloc@0\count` is from an old (pre 2015) latex and will only allow 256 \newcount, current latex allows 32000 counts so you should not run out.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have not ping me and I have not seen your message. I have understood your comment. The problem is the use of mtpro2 package (2009) fixed ans solved by great user Phelype Oleinik.

Comment: @Sebastiano eek `\alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt\pointcount@` in mtpro really doesn't work in latex, shoudl be reported to the package maintainer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your replay. But I think the mtpro2 package is old and  nobody will change the counter of these fonts.