# Enumitem package: how to create a fancy or awesome list adapt for a university book

Tags: packages, enumerate, itemize, typography, enumitem

Into my previous old questions (for example), [Vertical tennis ball into fancy new enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501808/vertical-tennis-ball-into-fancy-new-enumerate),  [Pretty enumerate: fontawesome](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499962/pretty-enumerate-fontawesome), or other my questions, I have asked a nice style as create a beautiful style of enumeration.

Unfortunately when each property is formed by a few lines, I can not use this style of enumeration because the symbols are overlapped. Therefore I have created my personal enumerate: see this MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{[\arabic*]}, noitemsep]
\item $A^{\dagger}$ è un operatore \textbf{lineare};
\item $(A^{\dagger})^{\dagger} = A$;
\item Se $A$ e $B$ sono due operatori allora: $(A+B)^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}+B^{\dagger}$;
\item Se $a\in\mathbb{C}$ ed $A$ è un operatore allora $(aA)^{\dagger} = a^{\ast}A^{\dagger}$ (con $a^{\ast}$ complesso coniugato di $a$);
\item $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$: l'aggiunto di un prodotto si ottiene prendendo il prodotto degli aggiunti in ordine inverso;
\item $\hat{0}^{\dagger}=\hat{0}$ ed  $\hat{I}^{\dagger}=\hat{I}$;
\item $(A^{-1})^{\dagger} = (A^{\dagger})^{-1}$.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}[label=\sffamily\textbf{[\roman*]}, noitemsep]
\item[(\textbf{I.})] Il commutatore soddisfa una versione della regola di Leibniz: $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$;
\item[(\textbf{II.})] $[A,c]=[c,A] = 0$, se $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Se ad esempio fosse $A=\partial_x$ dovremmo provare che per qualsiasi funzione $\zeta=\zeta(x)$ si ha: $[\partial_x,c]\cdot \zeta(x)=0$. Infatti $[\partial_x,c]\cdot \zeta(x)=\partial_x (c\zeta(x))-c\partial_x \zeta(x)=c\partial_x \zeta(x)-c\partial_x \zeta(x)=0$;
\item[(\textbf{III.})] \textit{commutatore di un prodotto}: $[A,BC] = B[A,C] + [A,B]C, \quad [AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$. Il fattore a sinistra si porta fuori a sinistra e quello a destra fuori a destra.
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item[(\textbf{i.})] $(u, v)=(v,u)^{\ast}$;
\item[(\textbf{ii.})] $(u+v, w)=(u, w)+(v, w)$;
\item[(\textbf{iii.})] $(au, v)=(u,v)$ e $(u, av)=a^{\ast}(u,v), \quad a\in\mathbb{C}$;
\item[(\textbf{iv.})] $(u,v)\ge 0$. Se $(u,u)=0$ allora $u=0$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

with this output,

[image]

There are many websites, guide how to built a [personalized](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/lists/) enumerate.
For me it is the first time that I am writing a book, but

*How could you create a numbered list different from of mine that I have created that is stylistically more appropriate to be inserted in a book?*

Comment: why are you numbering by hand like `\item[(\textbf{I.})] ` in an itemize (for unnumbered lists) rather than let latex number automatically with `enumerate` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In all honesty, I don't remember how to create automatic numbering.

Comment: of course you do, you do it in the first example, why not all of them?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For little roman numbers, how must I put. Now I'm editing my question.

Comment: change `\arabic` to `\roman` in the first list really the question is very hard to understand, the first two paragraphs seem general chat and not a question at all of your two questions you need to use `\label` and automatic numbering to use `\ref, and the second one isn't really a question that is clear enough to answer.

Comment: your edit makes it even more confusing, the second list you specify a label style but do not use it in any of the items as they all have  labels specified like  `[iv.]` so the automatic labels are not used, and the third list is still an itemize but with hand numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to number a list (and reference the items) use `enumerate` and not `itemize`.

I wouldn't make the number bold and sans serif. That simply looks bad. And I wouldn't suppress all the spacing - math needs more space, not less.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\item\label{eq:A} $A^{\dagger}$ è un operatore \textbf{lineare};
\item $(A^{\dagger})^{\dagger} = A$;
\item Se $A$ e $B$ sono due operatori allora: $(A+B)^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}+B^{\dagger}$;
\item Se $a\in\mathbb{C}$ ed $A$ è un operatore allora $(aA)^{\dagger} = a^{\ast}A^{\dagger}$ (con $a^{\ast}$ complesso coniugato di $a$);
\item $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$: l'aggiunto di un prodotto si ottiene prendendo il prodotto degli aggiunti in ordine inverso;
\item $\hat{0}^{\dagger}=\hat{0}$ ed  $\hat{I}^{\dagger}=\hat{I}$;
\item $(A^{-1})^{\dagger} = (A^{\dagger})^{-1}$.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item\label{eq:B} Il commutatore soddisfa una versione della regola di Leibniz: $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$;
\item $[A,c]=[c,A] = 0$, se $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Se ad esempio fosse $A=\partial_x$ dovremmo provare che per qualsiasi funzione $\zeta=\zeta(x)$ si ha: $[\partial_x,c]\cdot \zeta(x)=0$. Infatti $[\partial_x,c]\cdot \zeta(x)=\partial_x (c\zeta(x))-c\partial_x \zeta(x)=c\partial_x \zeta(x)-c\partial_x \zeta(x)=0$;
\item \textit{commutatore di un prodotto}: $[A,BC] = B[A,C] + [A,B]C, \quad [AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$. Il fattore a sinistra si porta fuori a sinistra e quello a destra fuori a destra.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
\item\label{eq:C} $(u, v)=(v,u)^{\ast}$;
\item $(u+v, w)=(u, w)+(v, w)$;
\item $(au, v)=(u,v)$ e $(u, av)=a^{\ast}(u,v), \quad a\in\mathbb{C}$;
\item $(u,v)\ge 0$. Se $(u,u)=0$ allora $u=0$.
\end{enumerate}

References \ref{eq:A}, \ref{eq:B}, \ref{eq:C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here is a working code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepacke[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{[\arabic*]}, noitemsep]
\item $A^{\dagger}$ è un operatore \textbf{lineare};
\item $(A^{\dagger})^{\dagger} = A$;
\item Se $A$ e $B$ sono due operatori allora: $(A+B)^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}+B^{\dagger}$;
\item Se $a\in\mathbb{C}$ ed $A$ è un operatore allora $(aA)^{\dagger} = a^{\ast}A^{\dagger}$ (con $a^{\ast}$ complesso coniugato di $a$);
\item $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$: l'aggiunto di un prodotto si ottiene prendendo il prodotto degli aggiunti in ordine inverso;
\item $\hat{0}^{\dagger}=\hat{0}$ ed  $\hat{I}^{\dagger}=\hat{I}$;
\item $(A^{-1})^{\dagger} = (A^{\dagger})^{-1}$.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item[(\textbf{I.})] Il commutatore soddisfa una versione della regola di Leibniz: $[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C]$;
\item[(\textbf{II.})] $[A,c]=[c,A] = 0$, se $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Se ad esempio fosse $A=\partial_x$ dovremmo provare che per qualsiasi funzione $\zeta=\zeta(x)$ si ha: $[\partial_x,c]\cdot \zeta(x)=0$. Infatti $[\partial_x,c]\cdot \zeta(x)=\partial_x (c\zeta(x))-c\partial_x \zeta(x)=c\partial_x \zeta(x)-c\partial_x \zeta(x)=0$;
\item[(\textbf{III.})] \textit{commutatore di un prodotto}: $[A,BC] = B[A,C] + [A,B]C, \quad [AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$. Il fattore a sinistra si porta fuori a sinistra e quello a destra fuori a destra.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item[(\textbf{i.})] $(u, v)=(v,u)^{\ast}$;
\item[(\textbf{ii.})] $(u+v, w)=(u, w)+(v, w)$;
\item[(\textbf{iii.})] $(au, v)=(u,v)$ e $(u, av)=a^{\ast}(u,v), \quad a\in\mathbb{C}$;
\item[(\textbf{iv.})] $(u,v)\ge 0$. Se $(u,u)=0$ allora $u=0$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Kind Bernard my question is different :-(. Sorry for my bad English. Have you an idea how to have a different fancy styles of enumerate? My MWE works correctly.

Comment: What would you like to have? B.t.w. I just wanted tho show the way to code  with enumerate could work without any overlapping.

Comment: I was looking for an innovative idea of an original numbering. However, I voted positively for your effort.